# Trusty - Sudo password?

Tags: permissions, sudo, password

I have a root user with password.
I have another user "ubuntu".

I have issued the `root@server~$ deluser ubuntu sudo` command.
The system echoes that ubuntu was removed from the sudo group.
However, ubuntu can still use `sudo -i` and gain `root` access.
I would like for `sudo -i` to prompt for the root password before allowing the user to gain access.
How can I configure this? Thanks.

Comment: That's not how `sudo` works, you need to use `su -` to do that root user prompt.  Or remove the user from sudoers (and remove the `ubuntu` user from the `sudo` group).  However, they won't be able to use `sudo` to drop to the superuser interactive prompt this way, to my knowledge.

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for your reply. You're correct, using su - does prompt for a password. My problem now is that even though user "ubuntu" is not in any administrative groups, the user can still issue the sudo command unopposed. 
Ubuntu's groups are: `ubuntu adm cdrom dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare`. 
Do you have any suggestions for next steps?